# Removing, then re-adding a commit down the road

Tags: git, github

At our shop we have two main branches:

`develop`-- which everyone branches off and eventually checks their code into, and which our automation tests run against after every commit.

`master`-- the 'production' branch, which the managers merge with develop before a release.

We're preparing a release, and a commit that made it from `develop` to `master` may need to be pulled out, owing to supporting infrastructure around it not being ready as soon as hoped.

I've done very few reverts before but would that be a good way to go here, revert the commit from `master`?  If so, when we merge from `develop` again will that commit once again be part of the merged code?  Or would we have to do something like a cherry pick to get it back into master?

Comment: Well, I haven't tried this, but can you get the commit that you dont want in patch form and then try to do a reverse patch (patch -R) on your master to back it out?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using git revert, see http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert. IMHO, you are probably in for a world of hurt because you then said you then want to revert changes made to the code base by some other person based on this contaminated code and that's going to be even harder to do.